# Numeration in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I wanna achieve numeration in jQuery. My current code works fine, but works for each div(.menu-item), I need separately.

My current code:

```
$('.menu-item h3').each(function (i) {

    ++i;

    $(this).find('span').text(i + '.');

});
```

Current effect:

```
.menu-item
    1.
    2.
    3.

menu-item#2
    4.
    5.
    6.
```

Need:

```
.menu-item
    1.
    2.
    3.

menu-item#2
    1.
    2.
    3.
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="menu-item">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <h3><span></span> Title</h3>
   </td> 
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: Sorry guys. I didn't show my full HTML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function to do this as by default `.index()` looks only at sibling elements:

```js
$('.menu-item h3').each(function () {
    $(this).find('span').text($(this).index()+1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-item">
     <h3>
        <span></span>
    </h3>

     <h3>
        <span></span>
    </h3>

     <h3>
        <span></span>
    </h3> 
</div>
<div class="menu-item">
     <h3>
        <span></span>
    </h3>

     <h3>
        <span></span>
    </h3>

     <h3>
        <span></span>
    </h3> 
</div>
```

After seeing your HTML, you can use `$('.menu-item tr')` instead of `$('.menu-item h3')`.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to go to each `menu-item`, then go though each `h3` in that. This way the `i` in the `.each()` function is reset for each `menu-item` you have:

```js
$('.menu-item').each(function () {
    $(this).find("h3").each(function(i) {
        $(this).find('span').text(++i + '.');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-item">
    <h3>
        <span></span>
    </h3>
    <h3>
        <span></span>
    </h3>
    <h3>
        <span></span>
    </h3>    
</div>

<div class="menu-item">
    <h3>
        <span></span>
    </h3>
    <h3>
        <span></span>
    </h3>
    <h3>
        <span></span>
    </h3>    
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work, because my HTML code is more complicated.

Comment: @blam4nz Well I guessed about your structure based on your code since I didn't know your HTML. Anyways you just need to do `find("h3")` other than `children("h3")` and it will work for your case. I've updated the code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You should "scope" `i` inside each `.menu-item`.

Try with:

```
$('.menu-item').each(function(index, $item){
    $item.find('h3').each(function(index, $h3) {
        $h3.find('span').text(++i + '.');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.